# Why do elements literally jump outside of their parents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

On this specific screen of an app I'm building, elements seem to and actually do escape their parent.

[image]

I'm using Django, TailwindCSS and AlpineJS. But after some testing it's clear the problem doesn't belong to any of these frameworks. On the back-end, I'm looping over an array to render the courses inside a `<section>` inside `<main>`. The first one obeys fine. The second jumps to the div above main and the third goes all the way under `<body>`

After removing both links to CSS and JS, the problem remains:

[image]

So the problem isn't in either Tailwind or Alpine. So I checked the page sources, which are fine! The way they should be:

[image]

I tested on Firefox Nightly, Edge and Brave, and they all behave the same.

The loop in specif that is being run is this:

```html
{% for course in courses %}
    <div class="rounded-2xl bg-gray-100 shadow">
      <header
        class="flex justify-between px-6 py-4"
        x-data="{ optOpen: false }"
      >
        <div>
          <h2>{{ course.name }}</h2>
          <span>Turno: {{ course.get_time_display }}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <svg ...>...</svg>
          </button>
          <button @click="optOpen = !optOpen" class="relative">
            <svg ...>...</svg>
            <div x-show="optOpen" class="absolute flex flex-col">
              <button>Editar</button>
              <button>Excluir</button>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div>whats happening??</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't know what else to look for. Please, if you have any idea of what might be wrong, please tell me.

Comment: Maybe something needs `overflow: hidden`? It's not clear what exactly the problem is.

Comment: My initial assumption is that your html is invalid. It shows in the source nested, but when the browser parses it, it breaks.

Comment: Do not put buttons or divs inside of other buttons

Comment: @dantheman ty so much that was it. Idk why the browser behaves like this, but I'll remember next time :)